# enumerate forms in BeforeNavigate2 event

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, events, bho, iwebbrowser2

I'm writing an IE BHO, I'd like to know how to enumerate forms in event callback. 
here's the code that enumerates forms in BeforeNavigate2 event, but the length is always 0.

```
STDMETHODIMP CEventSink::Invoke(DISPID dispIdMember,REFIID riid,LCID lcid,WORD wFlags,DISPPARAMS *pDispParams,VARIANT *pVarResult,EXCEPINFO *pExcepInfo,UINT *puArgErr)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    char bf[1024];

    if(!IsEqualIID(riid, IID_NULL)) 
        return DISP_E_UNKNOWNINTERFACE;

    if(dispIdMember == DISPID_BEFORENAVIGATE2) {

        IWebBrowser2* pSite = (IWebBrowser2*)pDispParams->rgvarg[6].pdispVal;

        IDispatch* pHtmlDocDispatch;
        hr = pSite->get_Document(&pHtmlDocDispatch);
        if (FAILED(hr) || !pHtmlDocDispatch) 
            return S_OK;

        IHTMLDocument2* pHtmlDoc = 0;

        hr = pHtmlDocDispatch->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument2, (void**)&pHtmlDoc);

        if(SUCCEEDED(hr) && pHtmlDoc) {
            CComPtr<IHTMLElementCollection> pColl=NULL;
            hr = pHtmlDoc->get_forms(&pColl);

            if (SUCCEEDED (hr) && (pColl != NULL))
            {
                long nLength = 0;
                hr = pColl->get_length (&nLength);

                if(SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                    sprintf(bf, "len = %d", nLength);
                    OutputDebugString(bf); // always 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return S_OK;
}
```

Why it always output 0?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just copy/pasted your code in my BHO and got a non-zero length collection.

Try that URL: http://linuxfr.org/ Use random user/password values and try to connect. That will trigger a `DISPID_BEFORENAVIGATE2` and you will get 3 forms.

So, it seems there is no form in the page your are navigating away.

Also, your code leaks memory and is not quite correct in using COM interfaces (ag: you should `QueryInterface` for obtaining an `IWebBrowser2` from a `IDispatch`.

Rewritten:

```
CComPtr<IDispatch> spIDispatch( pDispParams->rgvarg[6].pdispVal );
CComPtr<IWebBrowser2> spIWebBrowser2;
HRESULT hr = spIDispatch.QueryInterface<IWebBrowser2>( &spIWebBrowser2 );
if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) && spIWebBrowser2 ) {
    CComPtr<IDispatch> spIDispatchDoc;
    hr = spIWebBrowser2->get_Document( &spIDispatchDoc );
    if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) && spIDispatchDoc ) {
        CComPtr<IHTMLDocument2> spIHTMLDocument2;
        hr = spIDispatchDoc.QueryInterface<IHTMLDocument2>( &spIHTMLDocument2 );
        if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) && spIHTMLDocument2 ) {
            CComPtr<IHTMLElementCollection> spIHTMLElementCollection;
            hr = spIHTMLDocument2->get_forms( &spIHTMLElementCollection );
            if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) && spIHTMLElementCollection ) {
                 [...]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you manuell, I tried you code, outputs 3 forms for http://linuxfr.org, but not work for http://mail.163.com, the site has a form, but form.length is always 0, any idea on this site?

Comment: length is 0 because, at run time, the form in the main frame has a target attribute set to "frameforlogin", so the frame navigating is NOT the main frame. The HTML Document you get is not the one with the form. You may want to edit your question with precisions about what you really want to do

Comment: Now I know why my code don't get the form element on beforenavigate2 event. I don't have much expeience with Web development, let's continue with mail.163.com, the form has a "target=frameforlogin" attribute, and there's <div id=frameforlogin> inside an <iframe>, in this case, how can I get the form in BeforeNavigete2?  Does each <iframe> has it's own IWebBrowser2?

Comment: @aj3423 Yes each frame has it's own IWebBrowser2. Explain precisely what is your end goal and I may be able to update the answer.